# Ninja Forms 3 - processing form values on submission

Tags: plugin-ninja-forms

I have a ninja form that redirects to a thank you page.  I am trying to process the values submitted in the form to display different content on the thank you page.  I have achieved this in Ninja Forms 2 using the following code, but it doesn't work in Ninja Forms 3.  And I can't work out what to do with their example code given here http://docs.ninjaforms.com/customer/portal/articles/1981022-actions-methods-processing-ninja_forms_post_process.

Here is what I have successfully used in Ninja forms 2.

```
$form_id ='11';
$user_ID = get_current_user_id();

$args = array(
'form_id'   => $form_id,
'user_id'   => $user_ID,

);
// This will return an array of sub objects.
$subs = Ninja_Forms()->subs()->get( $args );


    $counter=1;

foreach ( $subs as $sub ) {
            if($counter==1){

$form_id = $sub->form_id;
$user_id = $sub->user_id;
// Returns an array of [field_id] => [user_value] pairs
$all_fields = $sub->get_all_fields();

 print_r($all_fields);

echo $sub->get_field( 34 );
            } 
            $counter++;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, I use this in 3.6, and adapted from Ninja Form Codex

1. create a js file to "listen"
2. create a php script to process

```
/**
 * File name: processNinjaformOnSubmit.js
 * Place in <themename>/assets/js
 * Desc: processes form data upon submit by "listening" for submit
 *    and then processing Ninja form
 */
 
var mySubmitController = Marionette.Object.extend( {        
        initialize: function() {
        this.listenTo( Backbone.Radio.channel( 'forms' ), 'submit:response', this.actionSubmit );
    },
    actionSubmit: function( response ) {

        //get the form id, e.g., nf-form-1-cont
        processForm( jQuery('.nf-form-cont').attr('id') );

    },
});

// On Document Ready…
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {

    // Instantiate our custom field's controller, defined above.
    new mySubmitController();
});

function processForm( form_id) { //form_id is passed by Marionette in the footer.php

    let result = form_id.match(/nf-form-(\d+)/);
    form_number = result[1];
     
    //get all the field names   
    let fields; 
    jQuery('#'+form_id+' form').each(function(){
        fields = jQuery(this).find(':input')
    });
            
    //build a name:value hash
    let nvhash = {};
    nvhash[ "form_number"] = form_number; 

    //populate the hash of name/values from all the input fields                    
    for (i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {   
        
        //get values of all checkable fields 
        if ( ( fields[i].type == 'checkbox' || fields[i].type == 'radio' ) && jQuery('#'+fields[i].id).is(':checked')  ) {
            nvhash[ fields[i].id ] = fields[i].value;
        //get values of all non-checkable fields
        } else if ( fields[i].type != 'checkbox' && fields[i].type != 'radio' ) {
            nvhash[ fields[i].id ] = fields[i].value;
        }
    }
    
    //use this data to populate a result page or record to database:
    
    jQuery.ajax({ //call a PHP script to process the form
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'https://somedomainname.com/wp-content/themes/themename/processNinja.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { nvhash:nvhash },
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response); //response is the returned result
        }
    });
    
    return false;
}
```

PHP:

```
<?php
/* Do something with Ninja form data */
/* Place in <themename>/ and call processNinja.php */
/* Fired by ajax call in processNinjaformOnSubmit.js */
/* In this example:
    * 1. the data hash is retrieved from the ajax call
    * 2. the field names for the form are retrieved from the Ninja table in the DB
    * 3. a associative array is built
  * 4. the data is inserted in a bestoke table of your making
*/

//calling a .php file via ajax requires we recall the DBI
$root_dir = '/usr/home/myhome/public_html/somedomainname/';
require_once $root_dir."wp-load.php";

global $wpdb;

$form_data = $_POST['nvhash'];  //get the name-value pairs from the calling ajax
$form_number = $form_data['form_number']; //retrieve one variable

//get the ids of the fields
$field_ids = array();
foreach ($form_data as $key => $value) {
    preg_match('/nf-field-(\d+)/', $key, $matches);
    array_push($field_ids, $matches[1]);
}

//get column names
$table_meta = $wpdb->get_results(
$wpdb->prepare( 'SELECT id AS fid, type, REGEXP_REPLACE(field_key, "_[0-9]+$","") AS column_name 
FROM wp_nf3_fields
WHERE field_key NOT REGEXP "submit" AND parent_id = %d', $form_number )
);

$name_values = array();
$placeholders = array();

//build the column/values asso array for database query
foreach ( $field_ids as $fid ) {
    foreach ( $table_meta as $key ) {
    if ( !empty( $form_data['nf-field-'.$fid] ) && $fid == $key->fid ) { //if there is data
       $name_values[$key->column_name] = $form_data['nf-field-'.$fid]; //build array
       array_push( $placeholders, '%s' );
    }
    }
}

// make the query
$inserted = $wpdb->insert(
    'wp_contact_me', //your bestoke table name
    $name_values,
    $placeholders
);

$wpdb->flush();

?>
```